# Save a Mail attachment as Active Storage object in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, rails-activestorage

I'm using Ruby On Rails v.5.2.2, Active Storage and 'mail' gem.

I'm trying to save email attachments to disk using Active Storage.

I cannot save directly the body of attachment as an IO, and neither save it directly into a Tempfile...

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution without temporarily saving attachments. It looks like this:

```
attachments = mail.attachments.map do |attachment|
  { io: StringIO.new(attachment.decoded), filename: attachment.filename }
end
message.files.attach(attachments)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I adopted:

```rb
mail = Mail.new(body)
# ...
att = mail.attachments.first

temp_file = Tempfile.new('attachment')
begin
  File.open(temp_file.path, 'wb') do |file|
    file.write(att.body.decoded)
  end
  @msg.files.attach(io: File.open(temp_file.path), filename: att.filename)
att.filename)
ensure
   temp_file.close
   temp_file.unlink
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is documented here: https://where.coraline.codes/blog/processing-email-attachments-with-active-storage/

Code snippet:

```
def process_attachments
  email.attachments.each do |attachment|
    next unless VALID_MIME_TYPES.include?(attachment.content_type)
    issue.uploads.attach(
      io: attachment.to_io,
      filename: attachment.original_filename,
      content_type: attachment.content_type
    )
  end
end
```

In the case of MailGun, `attachment` is an instance of an `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`. So `attachment.to_io` is the key there.